# Flutter: auto complete widget from reading items from text file

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement Autocomplete Widget and the items are present in a text file. While reading the file facing "A value of type 'Future<List?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List?'." What am i missing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ContractControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContractControl({super.key});

  @override
  State<ContractControl> createState() => _ContractControlState();
}

class _ContractControlState extends State<ContractControl> {
  //static const List<String> listItems = <String>['Apple', 'Banana'];

  Future<List<String>?> getData() async {
    try {
      String fileData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/instruments.txt');
      List<String> lines = fileData.split('\n');
      return lines;
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String>? listItems = getData(); **--> here**
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Contract Control')),
      body: Autocomplete<String>(
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
          Future<List<String>?> listItems = getData();
          if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
            return const Iterable<String>.empty();
          }
          return listItems.where((String item) {
            return item.contains(textEditingValue.text.toUpperCase());
          });
        },
        onSelected: (String item) {
          print('Item selected');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getData() is async method. It is Future method, meaning it takes some time to execute. It should be like that: `List<String>? listItems = await getData();` But it shows error because you are in build method which is not async. *The best* **solution** here is `FutureBuilder` widget!